# why does the int variable ' i ' change even without using it after changing the dimension of the char array

Tags: c, nested, iteration, nested-loops

i'm learning C so i decided to make a simple Tic Tac Toe game, i did the first version and it worked fine enough and this is the code for the first version :

int main()
{

```
char tictactoe[3][3][9],s,tic; // declaring
int r,c,p,t,i=0;

t = 10;
tic = 'X';

do{

    puts("                      Hello to Tic Tac Toe first version\n\n\t\t\t        Tic Tac Toe\n\n");
    p=7;
    s='7';

    for(r=0;r<3;r++)
    {
        printf("\t\t\t ");
        for(c=0;c<3;c++)
        {
            if(t==p)
            tictactoe[r][c][p] = tic;
            else if(t==10) tictactoe[r][c][p] = s;

            printf("     %c ",tictactoe[r][c][p]);
            p++;
            s++;

        }
        p= p - 6;
        s= s - 6;
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    if (!(i % 2))
        {
            tic = 'X';

        }else tic = 'O';

    if(!(i==9))
        {
            printf("%c's turn : ",tic);
            scanf("%d",&t);
            system("cls");
        }

    i++;
}while(i<10);

puts("nice you'v finished the game");

return(0);
```

}

after that i wanted to improve the code and noticed that i didn't need three dimensions array so i deleted two and just left one of'em " [9] ", however by doing that the do..while iteration integer value ' i ' always jumps from the value 0 to the value 57 at the last iteration in the nested for loop even though i didn't use it there whatsoever and it just happens at the first time the nested for loop runs where it doesn't add any more at the second and third time the loop runs,so why does the value of 'i' changed there?,  this is the code after changing (the only change is the dimensions of the array, and then i added ' i ' value test lines to see where it changed>>  'i' value testing 3 is the line where it changed value ) :

int main()
{

```
char tictactoe[9],s,tic;
int r,c,p,t,i=0;

t = 10;
tic = 'X';

do{

    puts("                      Hello to Tic Tac Toe second version\n\n\t\t\t        Tic Tac Toe\n\n");
    p=7;
    s='7';
    printf("%d\n",i);
    for(r=0;r<3;r++)
    {
        printf("1..%d\n",i); // 'i' value testing 1
        printf("\t\t\t ");
        for(c=0;c<3;c++)
        {
            printf("2..%d",i);// 'i' value testing 2

            if(t==p)
            tictactoe[p] = tic;
            else if(t==10) tictactoe[p] = s;

            printf("     %c ",tictactoe[p]);
            p++;
            s++;

            printf("3..%d",i);// 'i' value testing 3

        }
        printf("4..%d\n",i);// 'i' value testing 4
        p= p - 6;
        s= s - 6;
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    if (!(i % 2))
        {
            tic = 'X';

        }else tic = 'O';

    if(!(i==9))
        {
            printf("%c's turn : ",tic);
            scanf("%d",&t);
            system("cls");
        }

    i++;
}while(i<10);

puts("nice you'v finished the game");

return(0);
```

}

Comment: Usually this happens when you write outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: thank you so much it was that indeed, i just added one more index to the array and it worked @NateEldredge